# Prove that $f^{-1}$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, fake-proofs

Let $M$ be a compact metric space ($N$ is a metric space too) and let $f:M \to N$ be a continuous bijection. Prove that $f^{-1}$ is continuous.

My proof.

Let $A \subset M$ be closed. Then $A$ is compact. It follows that $f(A)$ is compact. Then since every compact set is closed and bounded, we conclude that $f(A)$ is closed and hence $f^{-1}$ is continuous.

I noticed that my proof didn't use the fact that $f$ is a bijection, so where did all these go horribly wrong? I would appreciate if someone guided me along! Thank you!

Comment: Why is $f^{-1}$ well defined?

Comment: Because ... oh... $f$ is a bijection

Comment: If you're interested, this proposition can be strengthened quite a bit and is an extremely useful result in topology http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Continuous_Bijection_from_Compact_to_Hausdorff_is_Homeomorphism

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use fact that you have a bijection for

$$f^{-1}\left(f(A)\right)=A=$$

Of course, you are also using that $\;\left(f^{-1}\right)^{-1}=f\;$...

Comment: I guess I must have confused $f^{-1}$ with the pre-image of $f$...

Comment: Indeed...yet if they talk of continuity it follows they mean the inverse *function* .

Comment: So is there anything wrong with my proof? (after including $\left(f^{-1} \right)^{-1} = f$ that is)

Comment: @ireallydonknow, no...but as a lecturer I'd expect a little more explanation of things from my students, in particular in such basic questions. That's all.

Comment: Right! I'll keep that in mind, to be as rigorous as I can be. Thank you!